# $\phi:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ alternating form of deg $2$. If $m$ is odd, $\exists v\neq 0$, $\phi(v,w) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations, exterior-algebra

> Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ be an
>   alternating form of degree $2$. If $m$ is odd, there exists a non zero
>   vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\phi(v,w) = 0$ for all $w\in
>  \mathbb{R}^m$

There are few theorems I know that would help to answer this. $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent, then $\phi(v,w)=0$. Is the answer based on linear dependence? Working with the definition of alternating form, I tried to do $\phi(v,w) = -\phi(w,v)$ but got nothing. Somehow I need to relate the dimension of the space with the existence of such vectors. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  Consider the matrix $A_{ij}=\phi(\vec{e}_i,\vec{e}_j)$.  This matrix is skew symmetric and has an odd number of rows/columns.  Therefore, its determinant is $0$ (the proof of this can be found [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix)).  Can you use this to show that there is a vector $\vec{v}$ so that $\phi(\vec{v},\vec{e}_i)=0$ for all $i$?

Additional hint $1$:

> Show that $(A\vec{v})_i=\phi(\vec{e}_i,\vec{v})$.

Additional hint $2$:

> Find a vector $\vec{v}\not=\vec{0}$ so that $A\vec{v}=\vec{0}$.

The $\vec{v}$ constructed in the two additional hints is exactly the $\vec{v}$ needed by the question.

Comment: I didn't understand the notion for the matrix. Is it like: $A_{11}$ is the first row, first column element? I didn't understand the notation $A\vec{v}_i$, but I guess that $A$ is the entire matrix, and that I must multiply it by $\vec v$ and get the $i$-th element of the vector, right? If so, I managed to prove the first hint. Now I must find such vector $\vec v$... Is there a general method to solve $A\vec v = \vec 0$? If so, then I can just cite this method and say that the solution exists, right?

Comment: also, why the determinant being $0$ in the matrix is crucial, as you cited?

Comment: How do I know the degree is $2$?

Comment: The reason that the determinant is $0$ is important is that means that the matrix is singular so the homogeneous equation has a nontrivial solution automatically (even though you don't necessarily know what it is).

Comment: You're given $\phi$ is degree $2$, you don't need to prove it.

Comment: $A_{ij}$ is the entry in the $i$th row and the $j$th column.  $(A\vec{v})_i$ is the $i$th entry of $A\vec{v}$ (since $A\vec{v}$ is a vector).

Comment: So since the determinant is $0$ the hint $2$ is automatically true, because there's always a solution? (i thought there were always a solution if the determinant was not $0$)

Comment: There is a *nontrivial* solution when the determinant is $0$.  There is always the *trivial* solution ($\vec{0}$), but that doesn't help you here.

Comment: Thank you, I understood. But the degree being $2$ is not used anywhere in the proof. Is it really essential?

Comment: Actually, the degree $2$ is used everywhere (just not explicitly).  For example, it's used in the construction of the matrix.  You can't generalize everything correctly in higher degree cases (for example there would be additional restrictions on $\vec{v}$ having repeated entries, which cannot be satisfied).